# Why is Ubuntu 10.10 refusing to upgrade?

Tags: 10.10

I had to reformat my drive because my computer does not support 12.04 or higher. Now when I go to the update manager it is not recognising a Internet connection. I have an Internet connection and it works fine this is confusing. My computer is a satellite A10 Toshiba laptop with a 75g drive and a 32 bit processor. All I want is for this computer is for it to upgrade to 11.10 so I can run it on my tv via vga adapter. 10.10 does not support this feature without going batty on me. Any answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify: "*.. my computer does not support 12.04 or higher*". Is this a specific issue around the: video card, CPU, RAM size, motherboard, etc? **NOTE:** *There is no longer support for **10.10**, **11.04**, or **11.10**. You should be using Ubuntu **12.04 LTS** (from May 2013 onwards).*

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it is possible to upgrade an unsupported release.. and if it's possible, it's not possible to upgrade to 11.10 directly. It is only possible to upgrade to the next release (so in this case, to 11.04) or from LTS to LTS (So for example, from 10.04 to 12.04)

So that basically means that the only way to get to the release you want is to do a clean install.

Comment: It is not possible, and NOT supported ..